# How to copy from current line to the `n`-th line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Suppose I am on line `10`, and I want to yank to line `20`. Usually I will do `10y`. Sometimes I do the subtraction wrong, and copy the wrong number of lines. Is there a way to copy directly from current line to line `20` without doing the subtraction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`V20Gy`, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: You definitely do, thanks. Simple and visualized way

Comment: This is a good approach, but visual mode is unnecessary. Since `G` is a linewise motion, you could simply do `y20G`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, probably then with `:set rnu` even better to use relative movements with `y20j`?

Less keystrokes (there is no shift needed), and there will be rarely more than two digits, meanwhile - in absolute mode line numbers can easily exceed four-digit and even more.

Answer (score 6):

The [`:[range]y[ank] [x]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Ayank) command allows specifying the range through the normal [cmdline range](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) syntax.

In your example, you could use `:.,20y` to yank from the current line through line 20 into the default register or `:.,20y a` to yank into register `a`.