# Copy entire line and paste it after another line

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Let's say I'm at line 20 and I want to copy (and paste below line 20) just the line 50. I can do that with `:50,50y` , then paste with `p` in normal mode. I found this [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9817/22625).

I want to know if there are ways to do it without that command nor using `50ggyy20ggp` (in general taking so many steps).

Comment: I'm using `50ggyy20ggp` but this is too long.

Comment: Still not sure what you want, `50ggyy20ggp` doesn't involve visual mode.

Comment: Mistake, I exchanged the words.

Comment: Doesnt `:50y` work?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Copy line 50 after line 20**

```
:50t20
```

Change `20` to `.` if you want to copy line 50 after current line.

**Move around and copy line after line 20**:

Go to line 20, and mark it:

```
mm
```

Move cursor to any line you want and execute an ex command :

```
:t'm
```

[`:h :t`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3At) is synonym for [`:h :copy`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Acopy):

```
:[range]co[py] {address}                                *:co* *:copy*
                        Copy the lines given by [range] to below the line
                        given by {address}.
```

[`:h :[range]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) is current line if omitted, `:h {address}` is mark `m` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer with `:t` is definitely the most convenient way to do it, if you’ve already used `:yank` then a good next step is probably

```
:put
```